# Custom AS3 Class not Updating

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5.5, document-class

I've had a similar issue to this, but the means that I solved the last one are not working here.

I have a custom class that consists of 12 separate .as modules. They're declared in the document class as follows:

```
import trailcrest.v1.s3.averta;
import trailcrest.v1.s3.chronos;
import trailcrest.v1.s3.eripio;
import trailcrest.v1.s3.fabrilla;
import trailcrest.v1.s3.gradua;
import trailcrest.v1.s3.lingua;
import trailcrest.v1.s3.navigare;
import trailcrest.v1.s3.pedem;
import trailcrest.v1.s3.praeferre;
import trailcrest.v1.s3.scriba;
import trailcrest.v1.s3.securos;
import trailcrest.v1.s3.sonus;

public static var Averta:averta = new averta();
public static var Chronos:chronos = new chronos();
public static var Eripio:eripio = new eripio();
public static var Fabrilla:fabrilla = new fabrilla();
public static var Gradua:gradua = new gradua();
public static var Lingua:lingua = new lingua();
public static var Navigare:navigare = new navigare();
public static var Pedem:pedem = new pedem();
public static var Praeferre:praeferre = new praeferre();
public static var Scriba:scriba = new scriba();
public static var Securos:securos = new securos();
public static var Sonus:sonus = new sonus();
```

This is a new version of the code. I am able to successfully refer to all of these classes and the public variables and functions inside in the "osr.as" document class. I can also SEE one module from another (i.e. Sonus can see Scriba using "osr.Scriba."

Where I'm having trouble is that, while the various modules used to be able to access all of each other's public functions and variables perfectly, after I added some new modules and variables and removed some old ones, **Flash Professional is still literally USING the old version. Inside of any module, the code hints are showing all of the old public functions and variables, and none of the new ones.**

I am guessing that this has something to do with some sort of temporary file that I can't get to. I absolutely need this working this week!

My .fla is "Tester.fla," and the document class is "osr.as." They're both in the same directory. Also in the same directory is the folder structure "/trailcrest/v1/s3/" which contains all of the Trailcrest modules.

Help??

EDIT: **Whenever I try to reference one Trailcrest class from another Trailcrest class (i.e. `osr.Sonus.foo`), I get...**

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.

I have confirmed beyond a shadow of a doubt all references.

Comment: Have you verified if this actually causes errors during compile time, my guess is it's just a problem with the code editor in CS5.5, based on your description it doesn't sound like anything is actually wrong, I would revert the changes then make just one change say to a public method name in one of the files, see if the code-hinting updates automatically, if not see if you can still just make the change manually where needed and get it to run.  If so it's just the editor not updating, perhaps restarting flash after changes would help (or use another editor if possible).

Comment: I edited these all in Notepad++. The code hints verify when I bring osr.as up on Flash Professional, and Flash Professional shows the changes in each when I open them up. The problem only exists when one module (such as Sonus) tries to access another (such as Gradua) using the means of referencing that has worked for almost a year now - i.e. osr.Gradua.{Function}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally figured it out. Here's the skinny on what was happening:

#1: Flash was apparently pulling an old version of the Trailcrest modules. To remedy this, I backed up everything and then removed all old instances of Trailcrest from my entire computer. Then, I put only the new modules back. That fixed the problem with Code Hints showing the old modules and variables.

#2: I had been experiencing Error #1009 whenever one Trailcrest class tried to access any component of another Trailcrest class, even though the references were all correct.

The cause was that I was calling functions on the various modules directly from the document class osr.as, outside of a function. This, of course, executes on the program start.

However, all the code within one Trailcrest class that called another Trailcrest class (i.e. `osr.Sonus.foo`) would not be able to access "foo" because osr.as for some reason or another hadn't finished initializing the classes before it ran the code that called them. This occurred, even though the problem code was well below the code that initialized the classes (see my question).

To fix this, I simply had to wrap the problem code into a public static function in the document class, and then call it from the Timeline. That ensured that all the classes were initialized before they tried referencing each other.

Needless to say, everything is running like a well-oiled machine now. How weird.

I'd welcome any explanation as to WHY this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the age old problem of what ultimately boils down to is the Verify Error. It happens when you embed "Class A" in one or more applications, modules, swfs, etc. Ultimately every output swf that uses "Class A" must be recompiled when "Class A" is changed. Otherwise you end up with a situation where 1 module has the newer implementation but others don't. This problem is compounded by the fact that the application domain is defined as a "first in wins" when it encounters a Class of the same name / package - meaning if the old one is referenced first, the newer one loaded later gets ignored.

The more permanent solution is to use class promotion to an RSL that ultimately allows the RSL to control the actual "Class A" reference in which it also implements an "IClassAImpl" interface that **all** modules use. This allows the compiler to cross link the reference with a signature it knows about without actually embedding the actual class itself.

Comment: Sounds about right, Mike. So, what steps do I take to solve this, because a lot of this is Greek to me...

Comment: If you're in a time crunch, when you update code to a class make sure everything gets recompiled (esp if it's shared between modules).

Comment: Okay, how do I "make sure everything gets recomplied?"

Comment: I thought you were using modules as separate swf's? If that's the case every FLA needs to be republished. This sounds like you're just using what's called a Class (gradua, lingua, etc) - are you certain you have a library path pointing to the correct physical location? If any of those classes are associated to a library item (base class or class) - there should be a verify / find / edit (don't remember what it's called) - if it can't find it then it definitely doesn't have the correct library path.

Comment: I only have one .swf. And I'm not entirely sure what you mean about library paths. I don't even have any code or anything in the .swf right now. The .as modules just need to communicate with each other. I've verified the paths in my question's code, if that's what you mean.