# passing custom events between modules through parent application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, flex4.5

I have created a custom event that I want to use to pass a string between two modules.  The event looks like this:

```
package com.mypackage.events
{
import flash.events.Event;

public class ThumbDeleteEvent extends Event
{
    public static const THUMBS_DELETED:String = "thumbsDeleted";

    public var files:String;

    public function ThumbDeleteEvent(type:String, files:String)
    {
    super(type);
    this.files = files;
    }

    // Override the inherited clone() method.
    override public function clone():Event {
    return new ThumbDeleteEvent(type, files);
    }

}
}
```

In one module I dispatch the event like so:

```
parentApplication.dispatchEvent(new ThumbDeleteEvent("parentApplication.thumbsDeleted", files));
```

and in another module I listen for the event like so:

```
public function init():void {
    parentApplication.addEventListener("parentApplication.thumbsDeleted", onThumbsDelete);
    }
```

if I use ThumbsDeleteEvent as the type passed in to the listener function like this:

```
public function onThumbsDelete(evt:ThumbDeleteEvent):void{
 trace("thumb delete event for thumbs: "+evt.files);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert  com.mypackage.events::ThumbDeleteEvent@26748a31 to com.mypackage.events.ThumbDeleteEvent.
```

if I just use Event as the type passed in to the listener function like this:

```
public function onThumbsDelete(evt:ThumbDeleteEvent):void{
if(evt is ThumbDeleteEvent){
    trace("thumb delete event for thumbs: "+(evt as ThumbDeleteEvent).files);
}else{
    var type:XML = describeType(evt);
    trace(type.toXMLString());
}
}
```

It works but does not think it is a ThumbDeleteEvent type class (it hits the else statement) the xml output of describe type says its type is:

```
type name="com.mypackage.events::ThumbDeleteEvent"
```

What is going on here?  If I put a breakpoint in the debugger it says the event is a ThumbDeleteEvent and I can see the files parameter and its right???

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you're doing. Have you tried cleaning the project or closing down and restarting your IDE (sometimes works in Flex/FlashBuilder)? If not, try renaming the class.

Comment: Yeah I have tried everything I can think of, cleaning the project restarting the IDE, renaming the class, casting the object every way I can think of - I am ready to start throwing things.  The data I want is right there, I can see it when I put a breakpoint in the debugger I JUST CAN'T GET TO IT!!!!

Comment: One clue that might be meaning ful to someone that has a lot better understanding of actionscript than I do is this - if I do a describeType on my object I get: type name="com.mypackage.events::ThumbDeleteEvent"  if I describe any other object, say string for example I get: type name="String"  It doesn't have the full path and the :: on it, I really just think I need to know what exactly I should be casting it to something like (evt as com.mypackage.events::ThumbDeleteEvent) which obviously does not work but there has got to be some way to get to the object.

Comment: This is probably an ignorant question but is the event 'imported' the same way in both locations?

Comment: And what happens if you pass it as 'event' but cast it to your event type when you receive it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that one swf has their definition of that class, and then the other swf has its own version of that exact same class. When trying to cast between them flash does a bytecode-check to see if the definitions are the same, and if you ever changed something in that as file without updating both with the exact same info you will run into this issue. That is, compile both swf-files, then change a space in the as-file, and compile only one swf file.

Urgh it's coming back to me, all those issues with shared code between different modules. I always just slug my way through these errors until I get it to work and can never really remember what it is since it can be so many issues.

- Make sure both compiled swf-files have up-to-date-versions of the file.
- Make sure both swf-files have same linkage-nesting to the code-file.

If that doesn't work [can't really remember since this issue is kind of like solve-once and copy to every other project].

- See in which order things are added to ApplicationDomain and make sure nothing else has their own out-of-date-version of it through something imported in flash library
- Move shared code into seperate code library linked in with "dynamic binding"
- Try with sharing the Interface instead
- Change how assets are loaded into the ApplicationDomain

---

Hopefully someone has more knowledge of this issue and can tell exactly what steps to use, but this is at least a starting point... I might have more time to research this and write a post about it sometime in the future later today.

---

Edit:
from another SO-thread [Custom AS3 Class not Updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352176/custom-as3-class-not-updating)

This is the age old problem of what ultimately boils down to is the Verify Error. It happens when you embed "Class A" in one or more applications, modules, swfs, etc. Ultimately every output swf that uses "Class A" must be recompiled when "Class A" is changed. Otherwise you end up with a situation where 1 module has the newer implementation but others don't. This problem is compounded by the fact that the application domain is defined as a "first in wins" when it encounters a Class of the same name / package - meaning if the old one is referenced first, the newer one loaded later gets ignored.

The more permanent solution is to use class promotion to an RSL that ultimately allows the RSL to control the actual "Class A" reference in which it also implements an "IClassAImpl" interface that all modules use. This allows the compiler to cross link the reference with a signature it knows about without actually embedding the actual class itself.

Comment: from another stackOverflow-thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352176/custom-as3-class-not-updating